# Embed Google Spreadsheet inside Google Apps Script Web App

Tags: google-apps-script

I am developing a web app using Google Apps Script where I fetch some JSON results from web. I'd like to present those results as a small spreadsheet embedded into one of the panels which is in the screen of the web app itself.

The idea is to do something like this:

```
var verPanel = app.createVerticalPanel(); 
verPanel.add(some_spreadsheet);
```

Is there any way how can I directly embed a spreadsheet object inside UI element?

Many thanks!

Michael

Comment: Probably, you should go for flexTable to display the data fetched and simultaneously, you can save it in a spreadsheet (if you want to store the fetched data)  . Here is an example of flex table. https://sites.google.com/site/appsscripttutorial/advanced-examples/create-table-from-sheet-data

Comment: Thank you Waqar! :-) That's exactly what I did. However, I wanted to let the user see the results in spreadsheet. Understand it not supportable at this moment.

Answer (score 2):

This is not currently possible.